# Does there exist an algebraic group $G$ such that all semisimple elements with infinite order lie in $G^0$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group over an algebraically closed field $k$.  If $G$ is connected, and $1_G \neq s \in G$ is semisimple, then $s$ lies in a nontrivial torus: this is Proposition 6.4.5 in Springer, *Linear Algebraic Groups*.

Now assume $G$ is not connected, and let $1_G \neq s \in G$ be semisimple.
The identity component $G^0$ is normal and of finite index $n = [G :
G^0]$ in $G$, so $s^n \in G^0$ is semisimple, and as long as $1_G \neq
s^n$, we can conclude that $s^n$ lies in a nontrivial torus.

But is it possible to have $s^n = 1_G$ for *all* semisimple $s \in G - G^0$?

Comment: Sure. $G$ could be finite of order $n$.

Comment: Yes of course.  But I was hoping for an example where $\textrm{Dim } G > 0$.

Comment: "as long as $1_G \ne s^n$":  this is true even if $1_G = s^n$, as long as $G$ *possesses* a non-trivial torus (i.e., $G^\circ$ is not unipotent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1847115/87579) may fairly be regarded as somewhat trivial:  it satisfies your stated conditions, but, probably, it doesn't 'feel' like what you want.  There's a good reason for that.  TL;DR:  it can only happen in a 'non-trivial' way if $G^\circ$ is soluble.

Namely, let $T$ be a maximal torus in $\mathrm C_G(s)$.  All geometric points of the coset $s T$ are semisimple, and, unless $T$ is trivial, not all geometric points of the coset $s T$ can have finite order.  (If $s$ has infinite order, then there you go; otherwise, we may simply choose an infinite-order geometric point in $T$.)  For an algebraic group to contain no non-trivial maximal torus is quite a strong condition; it is equivalent to saying that its identity component is unipotent.

Write $R$ for the unipotent radical of $G$.  Corollary 9.4 of Steinberg's wonderful paper "[Endomorphisms of linear algebraic groups](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=230728)" shows that $\mathrm C_{G/R}(s)^\circ$ is reductive.  Suppose for the moment that it is not the trivial group.  Then it possesses a non-trivial maximal torus $T'$, which is the image in $G/R$ of some (necessarily non-trivial) maximal torus in $G$.  (This is true in general for morphisms of algebraic groups, by Proposition 11.14(1) of Borel's "[Linear algebraic groups](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1102012)".)

Thus, the only way the situation that you describe can arise is if, for all semisimple elements of $G$ not belonging to its identity component, the fixed-point group $\mathrm C_{G/R}(s)$ is *finite*.  By Corollary 10.12 of Steinberg's paper, this implies that either there are *no* semisimple elements of $G$ outside the identity component; or $G^\circ/R$, hence $G^\circ$ itself, is soluble.

Certainly there are examples in this last situation; for example, if $G = \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \ltimes \operatorname{GL}_1$, with the non-trivial element of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ acting by inversion, then every element outside the identity component is an involution.

Answer (score 1):

The direct product $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z \times \mathrm{GL}_1$ (no need for the second factor, but you wanted a positive-dimensional example), where I abuse notation by using the same notation $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ for a finite abstract group and the associated constant group variety, is an example of the desired sort when working over a field of positive characteristic $p$, because all semisimple elements lie in the identity component.

In any characteristic, the direct product $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z \times \mathfrak{gl}_1$ (where $\mathfrak{gl}_1 = \operatorname{Spec}(k[x])$ is what is sometimes called `Add') has the desired property, for essentially the opposite reason.  (This is basically [@MattSamuel](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1827879/does-there-exist-an-algebraic-group-g-such-that-all-semisimple-elements-with-i#comment3736230_1827879)'s example.)